# Need Help to Format YouTube SAMI(.smi) caption

Tags: html, css, youtube, caption

I'm trying to format YouTube captions, to be more precise I wanted to add color and outline to the subtitles of my video. Quiet like this -

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Link to the YouTube video of this Images - https://youtu.be/KufDfy90fDo

I searched online to find out that YouTube supports some specific formats(.smi & .rt) for their captions which supports color attribute within the font. I tried to use both but only .smi appears to be working while .rt file is not recognized as a valid file by YouTube.

I managed to bring color to the captions, but now the problem is that I'm unable to make the outline or stroke on the captions.

Here is the code -

```html
<SAMI>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>phpg9Nnf2</TITLE>
<SAMIParam>
  Metrics {time:ms;}
  Spec {MSFT:1.0;}
</SAMIParam>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
  P { font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; color: white; background-color: black; text-align: center; }
  .ENUSCC { name: English; lang: en-US ; SAMIType: CC ; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<-- Open play menu, choose Captions and Subtiles, On if available -->
<-- Open tools menu, Security, Show local captions when present -->
<SYNC Start=220><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>Hello, everyone!</b></font>
<SYNC Start=1380><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>I will just type something random</b></font>
<SYNC Start=5710><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#FEFEFE"><b>These are supposed to be the subtitles</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8350><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>On YouTube</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8770><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>But I'm unable to get it Outlined</b></font>
<SYNC Start=10969><P Class=ENUSCC>&nbsp;
</BODY>
</SAMI>
```

By The Way, I'm a noob so please explain in Low-Level Language xD

Update: I tried a couple of things like **text-shadow:** & **-webkit-text-stroke:**, the code seem to be correct now, but YouTube doesn't seems to recognise the code..

```html
<SAMI>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>phpg9Nnf2</TITLE>
<SAMIParam>
  Metrics {time:ms;}
  Spec {MSFT:1.0;}
</SAMIParam>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
  P { font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; color: white; background-color: black; text-align: center; text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #FFFFFF,
     0   -1px 0 #FFFFFF,
     1px -1px 0 #FFFFFF,
     1px  0   0 #FFFFFF,
     1px  1px 0 #FFFFFF,
     0    1px 0 #FFFFFF,
    -1px  1px 0 #FFFFFF,
    -1px  0   0 #FFFFFF; }
  .ENUSCC { name: English; lang: en-US ; SAMIType: CC ; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<-- Open play menu, choose Captions and Subtiles, On if available -->
<-- Open tools menu, Security, Show local captions when present -->
<SYNC Start=220><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>Hello, everyone!</b></font>
<SYNC Start=1380><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>I will just type something random</b></font>
<SYNC Start=5710><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#FEFEFE"><b>These are supposed to be the subtitles</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8350><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>On YouTube</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8770><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>But I'm unable to get it Outlined</b></font>
<SYNC Start=10969><P Class=ENUSCC>&nbsp;
</BODY>
</SAMI>
```

```html
<SAMI>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>phpg9Nnf2</TITLE>
<SAMIParam>
  Metrics {time:ms;}
  Spec {MSFT:1.0;}
</SAMIParam>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
  P { font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; color: white; background-color: black; text-align: center; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white; }
  .ENUSCC { name: English; lang: en-US ; SAMIType: CC ; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<-- Open play menu, choose Captions and Subtiles, On if available -->
<-- Open tools menu, Security, Show local captions when present -->
<SYNC Start=220><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>Hello, everyone!</b></font>
<SYNC Start=1380><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>I will just type something random</b></font>
<SYNC Start=5710><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#FEFEFE"><b>These are supposed to be the subtitles</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8350><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>On YouTube</b></font>
<SYNC Start=8770><P Class=ENUSCC><font color="#E56B99"><b>But I'm unable to get it Outlined</b></font>
<SYNC Start=10969><P Class=ENUSCC>&nbsp;
</BODY>
</SAMI>
```

Comment: I haven't tried, to be honest, but this is the [link of the captions of the video you provided in your question](https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?hl=es&v=KufDfy90fDo&xoaf=1&caps=asr&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cxoaf%2Cxorp%2Cexpire&xorp=True&asr_langs=pt%2Cen%2Cfr%2Ces%2Cnl%2Cja%2Cko%2Cru%2Cde%2Cit&key=yttt1&lang=en&fmt=srv3). My advice is: keep searching, because in the given link, I can see the colors: `fc` and `bo` attribute. I suppose those are the colors and the stroke of the text. It would be worth it give a try. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know if [these instructions will work on YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM7Zz3xbca8). I hope you or anyone else find the solution and decide to share it with us. Good luck.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to be working. Still Thanks for trying to help.